# Collection Query Builder - orderBy multiple values

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-5.7

In my eloquent model, I have a location row. It holds 5 potential answers such as:

- Hotel
- Accommodation
- Library
- rest of the values

I want to perform an `orderBy` and want them to be listed as this order. Is there a way to achieve it with `orderBy`? Something like:

```
People::orderBy('location', ['Hotel, 'Library', 'Accommodation']);
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by _location row_? Can you explain your table structure a bit more (with example data and column names)?

Comment: Hotel, Accommodation, Library are data values, `location` is the table column name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you can achieve that by using:

```
People::orderByRaw("FIELD(location , 'Hotel, 'Library', 'Accommodation') ASC")
```

Of course, you may choose ASC or DESC.